# Web.config Rewrite Rule causing error "related configuration data for the page is invalid"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the error "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid." when i use rewrite element in the web.config of the WCF applications.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Index">
      <match url="myApplicaiton/Healthcheck.aspx" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="HealthCheck.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I want to the redirect (server redirect) if the request url contains "myApplication" http://localhost/myApplication/HealthCheck.aspx. Can you please tell me if there any issue in the above config and let me know if any other way doing redirect for the static files in WCF app web.config

Comment: You need to install  URL Rewrite for IIS:  http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 6):

You should install `Url Rewrite extension` in your iis.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You need condition, try this format

```
<rule name="ruleName">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myApplicaiton\Healthcheck$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="HealthCheck.aspx" />
</rule>
```